# Python can't find torch module

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, conda, torch

I'm simply trying to run a .py file, and not sure why it can't find the torch module. I am pretty sure all modules are up to date, and I can see the torch module in my lib/ folder...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ptb-lm.py", line 86, in <module>
    import torch
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

To be honest I'm still confused as to when / why use conda or pip but I did check that both were up to date!

Comment: Have you taken a look at this [page](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/4518)?

Comment: I did, tried all the commands they discuss, hasn't worked!

Comment: How about creating a new environment and install pytorch and the other libs? No `pip` is needed if you are in a conda environment.

Comment: In the environement, it does say that pytorch and pytorch-cpu is installed

Answer (score 0):

Try using anaconda to install torch.

Use this link to download https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/